# php checkbox checked on edit page

Tags: php, checkbox

I have 3 tables:

```
people:
------------------------
peopleID,
firstname

peopletype:
------------------------
peopletypeID,
type

peoplepeopletype (junction table):
------------------------
peopleID,
peopletypeID
```

On the add form everything is fine, but I have problem to display checkboxes checked for the assigned peopletype

Here is my code.

Retrieve data from peoplepeopletype table :

```
/*PEOPLE TYPE ************* */

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM peoplepeopletype WHERE peopleID=?");


    // set parameters and execute
    if ( !$stmt ) { echo "error"; }
    else if ( !$stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['peopleID']) ) { echo "error";}
    else if ( !$stmt->execute() ) { echo "error"; }
  else {
      $result = $stmt->get_result();

      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $peopletypeIDfromdb = $row ['peopletypeID'];
          echo $peopletypeIDfromdb; /*echo only for test purposes, but I don't know how to use this in the form */
      }  
  } /* end else */
```

Display checkboxes :

```
 <?php /*retrieve peopletype from db */     
 $sql = "SELECT * from peopletype";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
    echo '<input required="required" type="checkbox" name="peopletypeID[]" value="' . $row["peopletypeID"] . '"'; 
    if  ($peopletypeIDfromdb = $row["peopletypeID"]) { /*problem is probably here*/
               echo 'checked';
            }
    echo '>' . $row["type"];

}
              ?>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's the problem? Is none of the checkboxes checked even if the appropriate  type was attached to a person?

Comment: Can there be multiple types attached to 1 person?

Comment: @user4035   checkboxes are always checked (all 4) even if person has only 1 category. Yes more types are allowed (input required="required" works with jquery)

Comment: did you `var_dump($peopletypeIDfromdb);` after the first loop? Can there be multiple types attached to 1 person?

Comment: @user4035  tried        `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
       echo '<input required="required" type="checkbox" name="peopletypeID[]" value="' . $row["peopletypeID"] . '"'; 
        if  ($peopletypeIDfromdb = $row["peopletypeID"]) {echo 'checked';}
       echo '>' . $row["type"];
       var_dump($peopletypeIDfromdb); 
       
       }`       not working...

Comment: dump it before `$sql = "SELECT * from peopletype";` And still you didn't answer about multiple values. You'll need an array, not scalar in this case.

Comment: Yes more types can be attached to 1 person (input required="required" works with jquery). If I var_dump before $sql, I get int(1) before all checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can have multiple types attached to 1 person, you'll need to change the first loop to store all of them in an array. I store them as keys to have the minimum complexity of checking the existence of certain type in the future among the types assigned to the person.

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$types = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $types[$row ['peopletypeID']] = 1;
}
```

And then use it inside the second loop:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
    echo '<input required="required" type="checkbox" name="peopletypeID[]" value="' . 
         $row["peopletypeID"] . '" '; 
    if(isset($types[$row["peopletypeID"]]))
    {
         echo 'checked';
    }
    echo '>' . $row["type"];
}
```

Comment: GREAT!!! IT WORKS!!! Thanks! I will study your corrections to learn more! May ask what is = 1 at the end of $types in the first loop?

Comment: @codeispoetry Am assigning just any value to that key to make it defined.